# How to store numbers from a tkinter entrybox into an existing variable?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I just recently began programming and am attempting to create a simple mean/median/mode calculator with a simple GUI.  I have only found how to save strings to a variable, however I want to save only int's to my existing 'UserNumbers' variable.  I'm not sure if my code order is correct either.

```
mGui = Tk()

mGui.geometry('300x300+600+200')
mGui.title('Mean Median Mode')

mlabel = Label(text='Enter number sequence \n seperated by spaces', fg='red').place(x=7,y=25)
mbutton = Button(text = "Calculate" ).place(x=220, y=250)
mEntry = Entry(mGui, ).place(x=150,y=30)

UserNumbers=input("Enter number sequence separated by spaces: ")
nums = [int(i) for i in UserNumbers.split()]

Average = mean(nums)

print ("The mean is ", Average)

Middle = median(nums)

print ("The median is ", Middle)

if len(set(nums)) == len(nums):
    print("There is no mode ")
else:
    Most = mode(nums)
    print ("The mode is ", Most)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you have a GUI going, but have inserted `UserNumbers = input(...)` in the middle of 
it, this will cause an input window to come up, and then the GUI window, I don't think this is what you wanted. This is a GUI way to get an integer value:

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
nos = tkinter.Entry()
nos.pack()

def getnum():
    nums = int(nos.get())
    print (nums)
but = tkinter.Button(text = 'enter', command = getnum).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This is an input way to get an integer value:

```
UserNumbers = int(input('whatever you want it to ask...'))
```

I think that the GUI way would probably be better for you, as you can split the numbers up with the enter button, and include in the `getnum` function an if statement to test for whether a certain number of values has been reached, or have another button for when the user has reached the end of their list, this would stop the `mainloop`. But you can do either.

Hope this helps, if you need anything else just say.

Comment: If you're going to call `pack` on the same line that you create the button, it serves no purpose to save the result to a variable, as the result will always be `None`. Best practice is to always call `pack` (or `grid`) in a separate statement.